# sql - denormalize address

Tags: sql, denormalization

```
Customer Table - CustomerId, Street, City, State, Zipcode

ZipCode Table - ZipCodeId, ZipCode, CityId, StateId
```

However, what I am confused about it is - should I put CityId, StateId and ZipCodeId or should I put CityName, StateName and ZipCode in Customer Table? And should these be set up as referencing foreign key in city, state and zipcode tables? Should I get rid of City Table altogether and just repeat city's name in ZipCode table and Customer table?

Comment: One thing of note: it is possible that there is more than one city that shares one zip code (one that I happen to live in now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally, the customer table should only contain the street address and zip code ID (not the city or state).  Note that data entry for such a normalized scheme is not necessarily straight-forward; people will expect to enter city, state, zip code (or maybe just zip code) and the onus will be on the application to map that correctly and disambiguate when necessary.

I too live in a zip code used by two cities; they even happen to be in different counties, which leads to questions about which county I live in on occasion.  One of the cities has multiple other zip codes; the other only has (part of) the one zip code. There's no problem: you would have two separate ZipCodeID entries for the same ZipCode, one for each city.  Note that this means that there would *not* be a unique index on the ZipCode column in the ZipCode table.

Where would you store the +4 of the Zip+4 scheme?  Good question! That belongs with the street address.

Comment: I do not mind storing city, state and zip in customer table - my question is should it be cityid, stateid, zipcodeid or cityname, statename and zipcode?

Comment: Up to you...applications will be easier to write if you store strings.  OTOH, your cross-checking will not be as stringent.  The stringent checking might end up annoying people; there can be all sorts of quirks in the way addresses are written, and unless you're working with a current USPS database, or otherwise up to date with the minutiae of mapping and addresses, it is often wise to let people enter what they think is correct.  'Tis tricky stuff.  I'm leery of over-normalizing address handling.  That's why my answer started 'Nominally'.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to have more than one city with same zip code, then a better solution that you have a City table, where you have *zipcode* column (just varchar or int column, no foreign key). In **City** table you keep foreign key from **State** table. At the end you should keep *CityId* in **Customer** table.

Reason for this: City and State tables are small tables, and joining them you don't make performance problem, just make index on them and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks ok to me - keep full address in customer table. Just make sure that you permit to enter multiple entries into ZipCode table having the same zipcode but different cities (i.e. do not make ZipCode.ZipCode unique key).

[See here:](http://www.city-data.com/forum/raleigh-durham-chapel-hill-cary/991779-same-zip-code-different-town-tax.html)

> Zip codes relate only to the mail system and have absolutely nothing
>   to do with political boundaries. Some cities will be covered by more
>   than one zip code; some zip codes will cover more than one city.

It is very frustrating when you call insurance company and after telling them zipcode they would give you really bad quote - simply because you seem to live in different city across the road, and that city has exactly the same zip code, but bad crime situation.

Comment: when you say full address - do you mean cityid, stateid, zipcodeid or cityname, statename and zipcode?

Comment: Not ids, but strings. I would think of only one useful application if zipcode table - to auto-suggest cityname in entry form after zipcode has been entered, but even then still make city name editable (unless you have comprehensive list of all cities)

Answer (score 0):

You can also incorporate USPS address correction into your application to standardize and keep this information normalized. See: https://ribbs.usps.gov/index.cfm?page=aec